# Is there a way to have a Rust closure that moves only some variables into it?

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures, move-semantics, lifetime

I have  a general `struct` with settings and  an extra variable setting that I want to tune and play around with.

For all possible values in an integer range, I want to start a (scoped) thread with this variable set to that value. Depending on this value, they do slightly different work.

Each of these threads should be able to read the general settings struct.

```
use crossbeam; // 0.7.3

struct Settings {
    // ... many fields
}

const MAX_FEASIBLE_SCORE: u8 = 10;

fn example(settings: Settings) {
    crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
        for score in 0..MAX_FEASIBLE_SCORE {
            scope.spawn(|_| {
                let work_result = do_cool_computation(&settings, score);
                println!("{:?}", work_result);
            });
        }
    })
    .unwrap();
}

fn do_cool_computation(_: &Settings, _: u8) {}
```

This does not compile:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `score`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:12:25
   |
10 |     crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
   |                       ----- has type `&crossbeam_utils::thread::Scope<'1>`
11 |         for score in 0..MAX_FEASIBLE_SCORE {
12 |             scope.spawn(|_| {
   |                         ^^^ may outlive borrowed value `score`
13 |                 let work_result = do_cool_computation(&settings, score);
   |                                                                  ----- `score` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'1`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:13
   |
12 | /             scope.spawn(|_| {
13 | |                 let work_result = do_cool_computation(&settings, score);
14 | |                 println!("{:?}", work_result);
15 | |             });
   | |______________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `score` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
12 |             scope.spawn(move |_| {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^
```

This would invalidate `&settings` since the first loop iteration will take ownership of `settings` in a `move` closure.

The only easy ways to make it work were:

- copy the `Settings` struct into each thread (which in my real application is rather expensive)
- introduce an `Arc` around `settings`, which also feels a bit unfortunate.

Is there a way that we can circumvent reference counting here? Is there a way we can move `score` into the inner closure while still being allowed to reference `settings`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to move only one or some variables into a closure (rather than all or none).

Yes, this can be used to "circumvent" reference counting.

I found an answer in the documentation of [`rayon::scope`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.1/rayon/fn.scope.html#accessing-stack-data) that turns out to be exactly about this problem: 'Accessing the stack data [from within a scoped threads scope]'. That page also has an example that is clearer than the pseudocode in this question.

It turns out that you fix this as follows:

Use a `move` closure but refer to variables in the outer scope by shadowing them with a reference, therefore capturing them by reference rather than by value, using `let settings = &settings`:

````
```
crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
    let settings = &settings; // refer to outer variable by reference
    for score in 0..MAX_FEASIBLE_SCORE {
        scope.spawn(move |_| {
            let work_result = do_cool_computation(settings, score);
            println!("{:?}", work_result);
        });
    }
})
.unwrap();
```
````

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3fc1d15786092d676532e3b250f8c984)
So here, we move 'all used variables' but turn `settings` into a reference beforehand, so it is borrowed instead. (Pedantically: we 'move the reference' but that is exactly what a 'borrow' is.)

There is also a second possibility: Borrowing all variables (and moving nothing).

This possibility works in many contexts but not here. (Because here, we *have* to capture `score` by value as it will not be there during the next iteration of the for loop and the closure passed to `scope.spawn` will outlive this).

Taken from the documentation of [`rayon::scope`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.1/rayon/fn.scope.html#accessing-stack-data)

```rust
use rayon;

fn main() {
let ok: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
rayon::scope(|s| {
    let bad: Vec<i32> = vec![4, 5, 6];
    s.spawn(|_| {
        // Transfer ownership of `bad` into a local variable (also named `bad`).
        // This will force the closure to take ownership of `bad` from the environment.
        let bad = bad;
        println!("ok: {:?}", ok); // `ok` is only borrowed.
        println!("bad: {:?}", bad); // refers to our local variable, above.
    });

    s.spawn(|_| println!("ok: {:?}", ok)); // we too can borrow `ok`
});
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e15f66907cd5b65d6f8860e00df1b3eb)

Comment: Super minor nitpick here, but you're not really "circumventing" anything, you're just *not* reference counting.

Comment: @trentcl thanks! You are of course correct. 'Circumvention' is maybe a bit of sloppy language here. I have slightly altered the way it is written in the answer, but if you have better suggestions to make it more clear, feel free to propose one (and/or edit the answer yourself directly)

Comment: [Your second answer does not work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3fc1d15786092d676532e3b250f8c984).

Comment: Could the second answer be made to work with some modification?

Comment: @Jasha It cannot. Thanks for bringing my attention to this old answer. I have replaced the second example with the original from rayon::scope's docs it was based on, and added an explanation on why that situation is simpler/different from the one we have here (as here the spawn is nested inside a for loop).

Answer (score 7):

The [closure! macro from the closure crate](https://lib.rs/crates/closure) gives the ability to selectively reference, move, or clone variables into a closure.

Example taken from the docs:

```
use closure::closure;

let string = "move".to_string();
let x = 10;
let mut y = 20;
let rc = Rc::new(5);

let closure = closure!(move string, ref x, ref mut y, clone rc, |arg: i32| {
    ...
});
```

Variables that are captured but not listed default to being moved.